# Should the tag 'writing' and 'undeciphered-writing' be merged into 'written-language' and 'writing-systems'?

Tags: discussion, tags

Questions (I think all of them) with the (undefined wiki) tag "writing" can be merged with "written-language" and "writing-systems". Also "undeciphered-writing" has only 5 questions which can be merged with "writing-systems" imo.